# Python NLTK - Create own synset

Tags: nlp, nltk

What is the best way to create its own corpus of synonyms/thesaurus/synsets using python NLTK?
For instance - in the context of finance:

```
US
synonyms: United States, Washington, 
hyponyms: Wall Street
meronym: dollar
```

etc.

Simply creating a synset similar to wordnet but more suited to my purpose.

I am planning to start creating it by hand, and then implement an algorihtm to do it once the creation steps are clear to me.

But first i need to understand the principle of such a corpus. looking at the files in the Wordnet corpus i find the following list of files:

```
adj.exc  citation.bib  data.adj  data.noun  index.adj  index.noun   index.verb  LICENSE   README
adv.exc  cntlist.rev   data.adv  data.verb  index.adv  index.sense  lexnames    noun.exc  verb.exc
```

The content of those files is quite obscure, and really isn't helpful to understand how it works. All insights appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: If you're going to do all this work, I recommend studying the Wordnet documentation: https://wordnet.princeton.edu/wordnet/documentation/. It'll probably answer your questions, or lead you to the answer. (Section 5 is about file formats, which are  what you want at the  moment.)

Comment: On a related note - I'm also looking for a way to edit the current corpus of synsets using Python NLTK (for certain words only). I'll read through the documentation and see if I can find a path forward.

Comment: Any progress in this direction?
I am wondering what the data in data.POS and index.POS means